# Can I convert the given mips assembly code to c programming language to have the same results in the end

Tags: c

I have this type of mips code and I want to convert it to C.

```
.data
str1: .asciiz "hello"
.text
main:
li $t1,0
la, $t0, str1
Loop:
lb $a0, 0($t0)
addi $t1,$t1,1
addi $t0,$t0,1
bne $a0,0 Loop
```

The C conversion must have as variables the name of registers of mips and must be included the variable declarations. How can I do that?

I am trying to do that but I don't know how to declare the variables in C.

I am trying this:

```
int t1=0
char str1[]
char to
```

Is it correct?
How can I continue?

Comment: "How can i continue?" - Learn the C language.

Comment: You might have the same end result, but you might not get the exact same code at the end, depending on the compiler and such.

Comment: can you give an example of c for this code?

Answer (score 0):

I added some comments on your MIPS code and run it on MARS, The output is `hello`.

```
.data
 str1: .asciiz "hello"
.text
 main:


    li      $t1,0       # i = 0
    la      $t0, str1   # $t0 = str1

Loop:
    lb      $a0, 0($t0) # $a0 = str1[i]
    li      $v0,11
    syscall
    addi    $t1,$t1,1   # i = i+1
    addi    $t0,$t0,1   # $t0 = $t0 +1
    bne     $a0,0 Loop  # if str1[i] != 0
stop:  j    stop
    nop
```

The suggested possible C code is below.

```
 #include <stdio.h>
 int main(void){

 char str1[] = "hello";
 int i;
 for(i = 0; i < str1[i]; i++)
 printf("%c\n" ,str1[i]); 
 }
```